# gulp build through Gradle fails at install npm -failed for a project

Tags: gradle, npm, gulp

We have gradle and npm installed on Linux box inside jenkins container  where I am able to build through gulp build command but when I run

"gradle build"

> **Execution failed for task ':themes:portlet-layout:-portal-layouttpl:npmInstall'. 
>   A problem occurred starting process 'command '/var/jenkins/workspace/Portal_RTC/liferay-workspace/build/node/node..**

,I have got gradle npm installed and PATH set.I can say this running by npm --v , node --version.
I want to know what configuration I am missing to make it work.Also everytime I checked out the code I need to install modules again specially gulp else it start download from webhttp://mirrors.lax.liferay.com/nodejs.org/dist/v8.10.0/node-v8.10.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

when I define gradle-gulp plugin in build.gradle it says node is already installed. The imp things is the whole setup work on Developer machine on windows. Though they have copied node_modules folder from nodeJs home to their individual projects.

thanks